# Sass "argument must be a color" error

Tags: sass

I'm using Bourbon mixins and variable list in an @each, this combination isn't compiling because it's trying to run the function without grabbing the variable.

I'm wondering if I can optimize it this much or leave it expanded out.

```
$colors_list: ('pink' $pink $orange) ('blue' $blue $green) ('orange' $orange $pink) ('green' $green $blue);

@each $color_name in $colors_list{
  &.block-color-#{nth($color_name, 1)}{
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(shade( #{nth($color_name, 2)}, 50%),   0.75);
  }
}
```

Compile error:

```
Warning: C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/bourbon/functions/tint-shade:8: error: argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
Backtrace:
    C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/bourbon/functions/tint-shade:8, in function `mix`
    C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/bourbon/functions/tint-shade:8, in function `shade`
    C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/_site.scss:1267
 Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: Show us the compile error.

Comment: Warning: C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/bourbon/functions/tint-shade:8: error: argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
Backtrace:
 C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/bourbon/functions/tint-shade:8, in function `mix`
 C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/bourbon/functions/tint-shade:8, in function `shade`
 C:\wamp\www\dev.bodybenefitsbath.com/assets/css/sass/_site.scss:1267
 Use --force to continue.